# Android relativeLayout Control in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have been using the RelativeLayout in Eclipse, and it is very hard to control using the Eclipse graphical layout tool.  I'll start setting everything up and moving things around, and then suddenly, one move will throw all the other elements out of whack.  Is there a better way of controlling Android layouts?

Thanks